# iOS Tableview with 2 Data Sources/Delegates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, datasource

Is it possible to have a tableview on a view controller be controlled by 2 different data sources? I want the table on the view to show different table data depending on the segment control button that is selected by the user. At the present state it seems that the data source is always the last declared option. In this case, the missedEventLogController. Do I need to lay another identical table on top of the current table in the view?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLog: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var missedEventLog: UITableView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.eventLog.delegate = eventLogTableController
        self.eventLog.dataSource = eventLogTableController
        eventLog.reloadData()

        self.missedEventLog.delegate = missedEventLogController
        self.missedEventLog.dataSource = missedEventLogController
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need the one table view. Set the `dataSource` and `delegate` to one of the two sources and reload the table view. Each time you need to switch, repeat those steps.

Comment: That is a real Duh moment! Thank you sir...hope this helps another noob like myself out later!